# ASP.NET Core/EF Core 2.0 using too much memory that results SQL Server Timeouts

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

**tl;dr I am not cleaning up the context, as I assume that is all handled with DI/automatically being scoped (this might be my problem)**

I have a ASP.NET Core that utilizes EF Core and after a while my site being live, the memory on the `dotnet` process for the app shoots to 1GB, at that point I see a lot of SQL Timeout errors.  If I kill the process then those errors go away after the process re-spawns on a request for a while and it repeats..

I suspect somewhere in my code I have a memory leak or my design is not correct that results in something not cleaning up properly.

Here is my setup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMemoryCache();

   var connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("GeneralSettings:ConnectionString").Value;
   services.AddDbContext<CryptoCalContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
   ...
   services.AddScoped<IDbService, DbService>();
}
```

I pass the context to a service(DbService) handles all my DB calls

```
public class DbService : IDbService
{
    public CryptoCalContext DbContext { get; set; }
    public DbService(CryptoCalContext context, ...)
    {
        DbContext = context;
        ...
    }

    public List<CategoryDto> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            return MemoryCache.GetOrCreate("Categories", entry =>
            {
                entry.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(GeneralSettings.CacheExperationMinutes);
                return DbContext.Categories.Include(x => x.Articles).Select(x => new CategoryDto(x)).ToList();

            });


        }

    }
}
```

And in my calls to db, I do not make use of "using blocks" or call dispose.
I assume each call creates a separate db connection when needed so I do not do any of that (maybe this is where I am going wrong)

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IDbService dbService ,..)
        : base(dbService, ...)
    {


    }
 }

public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public IDbService DbService { get; set; }
   public BaseController(IDbService dbService, ...)
    {
        DbService = dbService;

    }
 }
```

In my controllers, I simply do `DbService.Categories`, one of many  different calls in my DbService, I put this example to illustrate that I do zero cleaning

**EDIT:**

```
public class CryptoCalContext : DbContext
{
    public CryptoCalContext(DbContextOptions<CryptoCalContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public CryptoCalContext()
    {
    }

    ...Properties...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {


        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: How much data is returned in your `DbContext.Categories.Include...`? It looks like it'll be pulling in two entire tables.

Comment: @GabrielLuci that query is very little *maybe 10 rows each with few children. That was just an example of a call I make to show I do no cleaning up.  I have other queries that are heavier in data return.  Problem is somewhere is not being cleaned up because If i involk all my db calls right off the bat there seems to be no issues, over team the 'memory' leak seems to happen

Comment: Is there a typo in you example in your `DbService` constructor at:  `DbContext = context;` Is that a property of the `DbService`?. If not, what is `DbContext` then? A static property somewhere? The way you're registering the DbContext seems fine. Maybe show us your `CryptoCalContext` class.

Comment: Are you sure the "memory leak" is not because of the `MemoryCache` usage?

Comment: @ErikBožič updated the example to include the property of DbService and added the Context class

Comment: @IvanStoev It may very well be but I am not sure how that is possible yet, because I do add a large set to memory in another method ,~1200 records with children (another 1200 or so) but the amount of data in these record is very minimal and  this is added to memory on the first request so as soon as the app starts these are loaded to mem and the size of the memory app uses when everything should be in mem is around 250mb in task manager.  Important point is that everything is loaded within app start so memory should not be growing that much over the time of the app process being alive.